# ControllerAdvcie doesn't handle all exception with GenericFilterBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I made a Filter using GenericFilterBean.

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
          throws IOException, ServletException {
          HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
          HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
          
          String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
          String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
          
          try {
              System.out.println(man);
              
              if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                 
                 Authentication authentication = tokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
                 
                 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
              } else {
              }
          } catch(Exception e) {
              System.out.println("yoyo");
                          
              response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token.");
              return ;
          }

          
          filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
       }
```

And I have ExceptionHanlder to catch every exception.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
    
    @Autowired
    private WebhookService webhookService;
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllException
        (Exception ex, WebRequest request){
        webhookService.sendMessage(ex.getMessage());
                
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), false, ex.getMessage());
        
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

And if you see in filter, there is an error " System.out.println(man);" since there isn't man variable.
But when the error occurs,  it gives the response of spring boot default. 
I defined response.sendError , plus,  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) just in case.
Both two method doesn't work at all.
How can I control the customized response in this case?
Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Why the `@RestController` annotation?

Comment: if there is not such variable called `man` as you said then your code doesn't compile.